# How to clear values in an array to a specific set in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

For a study project, i have to create a tic tac toe game.

I use an array in my game to keep track of the game board state. At start, the array contains numbers 0-8, as strings. The array is printed to the screen, as follows:

```
static void TableauDuJeu() // Je crée la fonction pr afficher le tableau.
{
    // Création du cadre/
    {
        Console.WriteLine("_________________ ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |     |     | ");
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  |", TableauMorpion[0], TableauMorpion[1], TableauMorpion[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____| ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |     |     | ");
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  |", TableauMorpion[3], TableauMorpion[4], TableauMorpion[5]);
        Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____| ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |     |     | ");
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}  |", TableauMorpion[6], TableauMorpion[7], TableauMorpion[8]);
        Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____|  ");
    }
```

When the player presses 0, the case {0} will be printed with a "X" or an "O"; this value will be stored in my array at position 0, corresponding to the key the player pressed.

The game finishes when a victory condition is up (so for example,{0} {1} {2} marked with a "X" or "O"; a new game starts; but my array still contains the "X"'s and "O"'s from the last game, which were stored in the array.

How do I clear the values stored in this array, and reset it back to contain numbers 0-8 (represented as strings)?

I tried `Array.Clear(TableauMorpion, 0, 9)` but my array is empty. Without the strings {0}->{8} inside.

How can i solve this problem ?

P.S : I am a beginner. So this problem might be easy for you !

Comment: So after someone wins, the array might contain {"X", "X", "X", "X", "O", "O", "O", "X", "X"}. Am I right? So what do you want to reset the array to? {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}?

Comment: Ok I try this ! Thank you :)

Comment: So after someone wins, the array might contain {"X", "X", "X", "X", "O", "O", "O", "X", "X"}. Am I right? So what do you want to reset the array to? {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "} I want to reset it with {"0", "1","2" -> "8"} my initial values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array and set the values to original (my understanding is you'd like to display numbers 0-8 as starting values):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    TableauMorpion[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

This is presuming your array is declared as a `string[]` (not clear from your posted code)

Comment: That's it ! Juste a single loop at the beginning of my do{]while(). It was very simple. Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reset it with {"0", "1","2" -> "8"} my initial values

```
TableauMorpion = Enumerable.Range(0,9).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

or just

```
TableauMorpion = new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };
```

Comment: Uhm... a bit advanced for a student project, no? :)

Comment: @CoolBots you're right i've added a simpler approach